# MyPy configuration - exclude multiple directories

Tags: python, mypy, pyproject.toml

We're currently using `Mypy` (v 0.910) in our project with `pyproject.toml` for configuration.

I have the following file structure:

```
src
  --app
    --generated
    --service
    --data
  --ingest
```

`pyproject.toml`:

```
...
[tool.mypy]
python_version = 3.8
disallow_untyped_defs = true
exclude = "(src/app/generated)|(src/ingest)"
...
```

When running with this configuration, the `src/ingest` folder is ignored, but not the `src/app/generated` folder.  To test the regex, I also tried:

```
...
[tool.mypy]
python_version = 3.8
disallow_untyped_defs = true
exclude = "(src/app)|(src/ingest)"
...
```

```sh
mypy src --config-file ./pyproject.toml 
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

which successfully ignored all files.  I'm wondering why the first example is not ignoring `src/app/generated` folder.

Answer (score 14):

for whoever uses `setup.cfg` file.
The following syntax is the one that worked for me:

```
[mypy]
exclude = folder_1|venv|tests
```

Answer (score 2):

Following should work:

```
[tool.mypy]
python_version = 3.8
disallow_untyped_defs = true
exclude = "src/(app|ingest)"
```

Comment: is this in `pyproject.toml` ? I found I couldn't use quotes when adding exclude to `mypy.ini` (so same syntax as above - without the quotes)

Comment: The single quotes are only needed if you have backslashes in your regex. This is due to how TOML parses strings.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this same problem -- it turns out you need single quotes for a `pyproject.toml` file:

```
[tool.mypy]
plugins = [ "mypy_django_plugin.main" ]
ignore_missing_imports = true
check_untyped_defs = true
disallow_untyped_defs = true
exclude = 'util/mixins\.py$|typings/.*\.py'
```

Comment: The single quotes are only needed since you have backslashes in your regex. This is due to how TOML parses strings. This is a helpful example; however, the statement that use of single quotes is the answer to the OPs question is inaccurate.

Comment: I have no regex on my exclusion list, anyway the problem was double quote :|